# How to manually switch between more than 2 signals in Simulink

Tags: switch-statement, simulink

Consider the block `Manual switch` in Simulink. It enables you to switch manually between two inputs. If you have, more than two inputs, a natural thing to do is to construct a cascade as shown in this picture.

[image]

Is there an alternative in case of many inputs, such as one manual switch with n inputs?

Note that I was wondering whether there was a 'manual' way to  do this. An alternative would be to use a multiport switch and set it with an initialisation script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to approach this would be to use a Multiport Switch.
This allows you to switch between several outputs based on the value of the first input (which you can tie to a constant block).

This way, when you start a simulation, you can choose the desired input by changing the value of the constant block in your model.

[Mathworks Multiport Switch Help](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/multiportswitch.html)

Comment: And you could maybe set the value of the constant by a scroll bar.

Answer (score 2):

A Manual Variant Source can be used. You can edit mask parameters to specify the number of inputs

Comment: For those who wonder how you do that: Right click on Manual Variant source -> `Mask` -> `Mask parameters...`

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the accepted answer, I achieved it using a Multiport Switch and a [Rotary Switch](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/rotaryswitch.html).